# Date notation for iOS in Dutch

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I'm implementing requirements from PO to show date and time in the application. We are targeting to NL, DE and UK market (with possible expansion further in the nearest future).

Here is my code:

```
formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setCalendar:[NSCalendar currentCalendar]];

[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
```

The problem that I faced - iOS NSDateFormatter returns date starting with capital first letter for the Dutch locale - **"Woensdag 25 februari 2015 15:42"**. As requirement we should have something **"woensdag 25 februari 2015 15:42"**. Of course I could "hack" it and add check for Dutch locale to lowercase the first letter. The questions are:

1. Are there guidelines about date notation for Dutch locale?
2. Is there better way to solve issue with standard API?

Comment: If you down vote question then please let me know why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS8 Apple introduced the enum [`NSFormattingContext`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFormatter_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSFormattingContext).

If you need it lower case because you want to put the date into a sentence that should be exactly what you want.

```
formatter.formattingContext = NSFormattingContextMiddleOfSentence;
```

Full list of options:

```
enum {
   NSFormattingContextUnknown = 0,
   NSFormattingContextDynamic = 1,
   NSFormattingContextStandalone = 2,
   NSFormattingContextListItem = 3,
   NSFormattingContextBeginningOfSentence = 4,
   NSFormattingContextMiddleOfSentence = 5,
};
```

Comment: Thanks Matthias. We still support iOS7. Another question - is it bug for documentation that I see only OSX versions but not iOS

Comment: I just used the first link google showed. It's available on iOS as well.

Comment: Actually we had issue only on iOS8. So you answer is perfectly cover our case. Thanks!